# fuzzy-c-means - setting initial number of clusters=6, but only 4 cluster labels generated

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, fuzzy-c-means

I use the  [fuzzy-c-means](https://github.com/omadson/fuzzy-c-means) clustering implementation and I would like the data X to form the number of clusters i define in the algorithm(I beleive that is how it works). But the behavior is confusing.

```
cm = FCM(n_clusters=6)
cm.fit(X)
```

This code generates a plot with 4 labels - [0,2,4,6]

```
cm = FCM(n_clusters=4)
cm.fit(X)
```

This code generates a plot with 4 labels - [0,1,2,3]

I expect labels [0,1,2,3,4,5] when i initialize the cluster number to be 6.

code:

```
from fcmeans import FCM
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from seaborn import scatterplot as scatter

# fit the fuzzy-c-means
fcm = FCM(n_clusters=6)
fcm.fit(X)

# outputs
fcm_centers = fcm.centers
fcm_labels  = fcm.u.argmax(axis=1)

# plot result
%matplotlib inline
f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(11,5))
scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], ax=axes[0])
scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], ax=axes[1], hue=fcm_labels)
scatter(fcm_centers[:,0], fcm_centers[:,1], ax=axes[1],marker="s",s=200)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please include details of which implementation you are using and the relevant imports - if it is not `skfuzzy`, please remove the (added by myself) tag

Comment: It is an implementation from fcmeans. But the problem is not with the implementation, even with skfuzzy I see the same behavior.

Comment: We always need the implementation, in order to try to *reproduce* the behavior...

Comment: Thanks! added the whole code used, and the implementation is fcmeans

Comment: But i mainly need to understand this cluster results. In general, we can expect the number of clusters of defined(in my case n=6) as the outputted cluster right? Or will the output vary from the given number of clusters?

Comment: I would *suspect* that, if the algorithm cannot find "enough" clusters, it does not respect the `n_clusters` argument, and it effectively treats it as the max number of clusters to search for; but that is just my suspicion, I would like to experiment myself, but unfortunately I cannot install the package (`pip` does not seem to work).

Comment: Thanks thats my suspiction too! pip install fuzzy-c-means worked for me though!

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy c-means is a *fuzzy* clustering algorithm.

The labels are only an approximation to the fuzzy assignment.

Most likely two clusters are pretty weak, and hence never win the `argmax` operation used to produce the labels. That doesn't mean these clusters have not been used, you are just not using the full fuzzy result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `fuzzy-c-means` version `1.7.0`:

```
>>> import fcmeans
>>> fcmeans.__version__
'1.7.0'
```

Using synthetic data:

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>>> iris = load_iris().data
>>> model = fcmeans.FCM(n_clusters = 2)
>>> model.fit(iris)
>>> pred = model.predict(iris)
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(pred)
Counter({0: 97, 1: 53})
```

So, the `n_clusters` applied correctly.

Answer (score -2):

I read about it and looks like once the algorithm reaches the knee point(max number of clusters it can perform with the data), it wont create anything more than this. So in my question, 4 was the maximum number of clusters that the algo perform with the given dataset.

Comment: No. It does not use a "knee" point. There is no reliable mathematical definition of this that it could even use. You're misinterpreting the result by using `argmax`.